# Copy multiple sheets multiple times

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

Thanks for building up a strong community for novice people like us.

I was trying to build up a macro which copies multiple selected sheets multiple times based on user input through google search and I am facing some trouble.

Issue here is that while the code does copy multiple sheets multiple times but it loses linking.

For example - I have sheets titled as A, B and C in the workbook and sheet B has some cells linked to sheet A, similarly Sheet C has some values linked to sheet B, when this macro is used, it creates copies of the sheets one at a time. So if I mention 4 copies after selecting Sheet B and C, it will create 1st copy of B, then 1st copy of C, then second copy of B and then second copy of C and so on till the loop ends.

However what I want is that It selects the two sheets together and then create copies. This is because when we manually do it, the linking in the sheets gets revised to the newly created sheets. What I mean here is that when we select Sheet B and C and then manually create a copy, Sheet C will show linking to newly created sheet B.

I am not sure if this could be done through VBA but posts show that this can be done through some array function which I am not aware of.

Any help will be much appreciated.

I am not sure how to add a file or to add a code that I have to this forum I have hence added it here

```
Sub MultiSheetArray()

'allows you to store an array of sheets

Dim ws As Worksheet

Dim ShtArray() As String

Dim intA As Integer

Dim intB As Integer
Dim myArray() As Variant

 Dim i As Long
 On Error GoTo endit
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 shts = InputBox("How many times")

' First you need to enter the sheet names into an array

For Each ws In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

 intA = intA + 1

 ReDim Preserve ShtArray(intA)

 ShtArray(intA) = ws.Name

Next ws



' Now list the sheets we entered into our array "shtArray"

 For i = 1 To shts

For intB = 1 To intA

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(myArray(x)).Copy after:=ActiveSheet

Next intB

 Next i
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
endit:


End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am open to any other code that does the same function.

Comment: Try using the macro recorder when you manually accomplish the task, to see what code is produced.

Comment: It gives me an array of sheets. Those sheets are hardcoded. I wanted it to be dynamic

Sub abc()
'
' ABC Macro
'

'
    Sheets(Array("A", "B", "C")).Select
    Sheets("C").Activate
    Sheets(Array("A", "B", "C")).Copy before:=Sheets(4)
End Sub

Comment: I am sorry I don't know how to mention the code in a code window. Thank you @GSD for helping modifying the original post

Comment: How are you populating "myArray(x)" ?  It looks like it should work and then Excel will add (2), (3), (4) after every copy it makes.

Comment: I am not sure how to answer that. I copied the code from somewhere. It surely does create copies but retains linking to original sheets and not the newly created sheet which it does when we go about it manually. What I want is that it modify the linking to newly created sheets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Copy Multiple Instances of Selected Worksheets

- To test this procedure, open a new workbook. In `VBE` <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, insert a standard module and copy the code into it. Add a few worksheets. Now select some of them by clicking on the tab for the first one and <kbd>CRTL</kbd>-clicking on any others' tab which will create a group of worksheets. Now run the procedure which will firstly ask "How many times". For the first time do not enter more than `2` and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> and see what has happened.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

' Copies selected sheets multiple times after the last sheet.
Sub MultiSheetArray()
    
    On Error GoTo endit
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Input number of copies.
    Dim shts As Long
    shts = InputBox("How many times")
    
    ' Write the names of the selected sheets to an array.
    Dim sh As Object
    Dim ShtArray() As String
    ReDim ShtArray(1 To ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count)
    Dim i As Long
    For Each sh In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        i = i + 1
        ShtArray(i) = sh.Name
    Next sh
    
    ' Copy sheets after last sheet.
    For i = 1 To shts
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .Sheets(ShtArray).Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
        End With
    Next i
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

endit:

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi VBasic2008. Thanks for the code. I tried to run the code but it throws multiple errors like intA not defined. I defined it as an integer. Then it showed I not defined which I see is defined by you. Can you check if it shows the same error for you too. Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot for your help. I really appreciate it. I am sure this will be helpful for multiple community users.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Side note: after declaring `Dim ShtArray() As String` you could define the final array dimension in advance in order to avoid multiple `ReDim Preserve` transformations within the loop: `ReDim ShtArray(1 To ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Count)` :-)

Comment: @T.M.: Thanks, it's a must in my book. I've seen it in the beginning, but I got overly consumed by the fact, that the references really got changed.I didn't even know that this was manually possible.